# Issue with gridview pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have displayed user details using a gridview. Given linkbutton for username column when user click, it redirects to the respective user view details page.

I am facing an issue with pagination. When I click a username on the second page, details are not shown, all field values are blank.

Here is my `rowCommand` code

```
if (e.CommandName == "view_User")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) % UserGridView.PageSize;
    GridViewRow viewRowUser = UserGridView.Rows[index];
    Response.Redirect("~/viewUser.aspx?userid=" + viewRowUser.Cells[0].Text);
}
```

While debug I have observed that the `viewRowUser.Cells[0].Text` value is blank and it shows correct values for all rows of page 1.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not send the contents of `viewRowUser.Cells[0].Text` as the CommandArgument instead of your roundabout way?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userid") %>' CommandName="view_User" runat="server">View User</asp:LinkButton>
```

And then in code behind.

```
if (e.CommandName == "view_User")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/viewUser.aspx?userid=" + e.CommandArgument);
}
```